# Html entities in tcpdf

Tags: php, html-entities, tcpdf

I am using tcpdf to generate the pdf but I got the problem while displaying the strings having html entities in it. e.g A string  `RAH&#304;B` is displayed as RAH?B whereas I just want to decode this entity and display it as RAHİB.I am using UTF-8 as character-set.I tried to use html_entity_decode function but this doesn't work.

Any help would be highle appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

There is a TCPDF function called `unhtmlentities` that has worked for me.

https://tcpdf.org/docs/srcdoc/tcpdf/class-TCPDF/#_unhtmlentities

Comment: Path changed: http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#ae4bdb1a4c29d0a0d707caad308dcd320